# Why does my Pearson correlation coefficient (and MSE) keep changing every time I run the program?

Tags: scikit-learn, scipy, python-3.7, pearson-correlation, mean-square-error

Is it normal for the values to change every time I run the same piece of code that trains the data sets, predicts values on a test set and then computes the correlation coefficients and MSE values? Why does this happen?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from scipy.stats import linregress

training = pd.read_csv('csvfile1.csv')    #training data set
target = pd.DataFrame(training, columns=['target_column'])  #target 
testing = pd.read_csv('csvfile2.csv')    #test set loaded from a different file
true = pd.DataFrame(testing, columns=['predicted_value'])  #for comparison after predicting the target 
X_train = training
target_vec = target['target_column']
Y_test = training
regression = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='mse', splitter='best')
model = regression.fit(X_train, target_vec)
output = regression.predict(Y_test)  #predictions
print(linregress(output, true.predicted_value))   #printing out rvalue
```

Comment: Where do I use it exactly?

Comment: put it above any place where you use random numbers. Close to the top, ideally.

Comment: If you don't share a minimal working example of your code, any answers are going to be pure guesswork.

Comment: This cannot be meaningfully answered without code.

Comment: Edited a bit of code into it. Please check again.

Comment: Does it still do the same thing after you added random.seed(123)?

Comment: If so, that might be something about the nature of the DecisionTreeRegressor, it may generate different decision points each time.

Comment: I did add the random seed. It doesn't seem to have had an effect.

Comment: If the data is the same every time, the difference would then be in the way the model is fitted in the regressor. Check the documentation for that. I can look into it later, gotta get back to work.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

`import random
random.seed(123)`

The number doesn't really matter, the point is, it set's the pseudo-random generator to the same same starting point each time.

My guess is that you must be splitting the data into train and test sets randomly, and this is different each time. Next time show us your code. You may get voted down for not doing that. It also helps us to help you.